# Export modified Administration Views

Tags: views

I am using [Aministration Views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views) module to have a custom page for content list. I have added some new columns to the view and now I want to export all that in a Features so I can deploy it on my staging server. The problem is that I just can't export it in a feature, when I create the feature, it is just "empty", there is only a depedancy to admin_views but I can't see changes I have made.

Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: I just supplied a fairly comprehensive answer to a very similar question over at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/130957/5036.

Answer (score 1):

To export a view, go to http://example.org/admin/structure/views/view/your_view/export
Then wrap it into a module using [hook_views_default_views()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_default_views/7) and export that module.

Not the easiest way, but reliable.

Comment: Thanks, that can be one solution. I have just found another suggestion from http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41228/cannot-track-view-with-features

Comment: Both solutions have one in common: original view definition is not exported, and that looks like features bug. Will you clone it in database, or on disk, hardly matters, I find spirit of both our answers pretty similar. Actually, the answer you linked to may be closer to what you had in mind and easier to use in long term perspective.