# How to "featurize" customizations to Answers module (or a content type that is part of a module)

Tags: features, 7

I'm implementing a discussion feature using the Answers module. I want to create a feature for all the customizations so I can implement and deploy using the git process.

The views and content types that I've customized (answers and questions) are not showing up as options to include in the feature.

Has anyone else worked with this module with git for local, staging/testing and production? How did you push your customizations? Thanks!

Drupal 7.54; Answers 7.x-4.0-rc2

Edit: Answers is a contributed module that comprises of some views and some content types and possible other components.

Edit 2: I've followed the advice in this [SE post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41228/cannot-track-view-with-features?rq=1) regarding a similar situation in views, but it doesn't solve my issue with content types or having to basically re-create the module.

Answer (score 0):

For the customized views, I cloned and disabled the original views. Then I was able to pull the view (cloned one) into the feature.

For the content type customizations, I was able to pull in the new fields I created, and customizations to the other fields, by finding the names of the specific customized fields in field bases and strongarm in features.